# What does it mean when an aircraft engine is de-paired?

Tags: jet-engine, terminology

What does it mean when an aircraft engine is de-paired? e.g. the PW1000g engines being de-paired because of issues in the LPT or the Rolls Royce Trent 1000 engines due to excessive corrosion on some of the turbine blades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De-pairing means literally braking up pairs. In the case in question, it means that if an aircraft is equipped with engines of a certain specific type, one of the engines has to be replaced with a version that has been upgraded.

The reason for the de-pairing is to mitigate the risk of a dual engine failure: Having two engines that are both affected by the same issue considerably increases the risk of both engines failing on the same flight. At least RR Trent 1000 and P&W 1100G have been issued a de-pairing AD by EASA.

[Article on RR Trent 1000 de-pairing AD on Airlineratings.com](https://www.airlineratings.com/news/easa-orders-airlines-de-pair-rolls-royce-787-engines/)

[Article on P&W 1100G de-pairing AD on samchui.com](https://samchui.com/2019/12/18/easa-requires-de-pairing-of-a320neo-pw-engines/#.XgYQWmTkt6g)